# ajax and js works in chrome but dont works correctly in mozilla and IE (codeigniter)

Tags: javascript, ajax, codeigniter, google-chrome, mozilla

im doing autocomplete system in my website with codeigniter. But i have problems. I can do this works in Chrome, but in mozilla and IE dont works. For example, in chrome open the itens of result them query in dropdown list, and the mozilla and IE appears "2 results are available, use up and down arrow keys to navigate." Verify screenshots

The View (autoComplete_v.php):

```
    <head>
    <link href="../../css/ui-lightness/jquery-ui-1.10.3.custom.css" media="screen" type="text/stylesheet" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>
<body>

    <form>
        <label for="search">Search</label>
        <input id="search" type="text"/>
        <input id="hiddenurl" type="hidden">
        <input type="submit" value="submit"/>
    </form>

    <script src="<?php base_url();?>../../js/jquery-1.9.1.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="<?php base_url();?>../../js/jquery-ui-1.10.3.custom.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="<?php base_url();?>../../js/autocomplete.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

The js file (autocomplete.js):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 $('#search').keypress(function(e){
        if(e.which == 13)
            {
                e.preventDefault();
            }
            var searched = $('#search').val()
            var fullurl = $('#hiddenurl').val() + '../autoComplete_c/getResult/' + searched
        $.getJSON(fullurl,function(result){
           //display suggestion code goes here
           var elements = [];
           $.each(result, function(i, val){
               elements.push(val.referencia)
           })
           $('#search').autocomplete({
               source : elements
           })
        })             
    });
});
```

The controller (autoComplete_c.php):

```
public function getResult($referencia){
     if(!empty($referencia) || isset($referencia))
     {
         $this->db->select('referencia');
         $this->db->like('referencia', $referencia);
         echo json_encode( $this->db->get('produto_servico_tbl')->result());
     }
}
```

Chrome: [image]

Mozilla and IE:

[image]

Comment: You should probably explain what's wrong. "It's not working" and a screenshot with a red box are not very descriptive.

Comment: edited. Can you understand now?